# Js regex test except string

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this list:

```
tests.skills
tests.instructions
tests.something
```

I want to test if the given string include any of the last two but not the first one, so i tried this:

```
 var str = 'tests.instructions';
 if( /tests\.[^skills].+/ig.test(str) ) {
      console.log(1);
  }
```

But it does not work, how can i test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/tests\.(?!skills).+/
```

The set negation `[^x]` will try to match a character that is not `x`. What `[^skills]` actually means is *match a single character, which is not `s` or `k` or `i` or `l` or `l` or `s`*.

Instead a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!sequence)` will do the job.

Comment: You can explain what your regex do?

Comment: @user233232, I guess you already know everything except for the `(?!)` part. It is called a negative lookahead. Basically, what it does is matches an empty string if what follows in the current position is not `skills` and fails the entire match otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
tests\.(?:instructions|something)
```

It means: search for `tests.` text which is followed by `instructions` *or* `something`.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/eT3eF1/2)